# Importing from World Creator 2 to Blender 2.83 - Best Practices

Tags: import, workflow

I am at a stalemate here. The goal is to bring in a landscape from WC2 to Blender and have it look as photorealistic as possible.

Is it better to create as much as possible in WC2 (mesh, texture, vegetation, etc.) and import all that into blender or just the mesh from WC2 and build from there?

I wonder, too, if there is a preferred method to bring in a mesh, import as a .obj or use an exported height map to use a displacement.